# What should the urls.py be like in django for this particular query?

Tags: django

When a link is clicked ( Which is generated from a search result ) , it should take the name/primary key of that particular data to a view . I have read through the documentation of URL dispatcher , but haven't got a concrete idea of how to pass the primary key of a certain row of a table to another view .

Any help is much appreciated .

Till now I have done this .

```
def that_view ( request , num) 
---view code
```

search is generating a particular Url . When I click on that , the primary key should pass to this that_view to be processed to view the data .

Is this the right way to do it , if yes how exactly should I modify my urls.py and also the template that generates the data search (i.e the url) .

You might ask me to read the documentation , again and again . But I did . No help . Any code snippet of any kind ( even a link to such, and not a link to the documentation ) would help .

This is my views .

```
def map_search(request):
     lcount = Open_Layers.objects.all()

     form = SearchForm()
     if request.method == 'POST': 
            form = SearchForm(request.POST) 
            if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
                    val=form.cleaned_data['LayerName']

            a=OsmLayers()
                        b=Open_Layers()
            c=Sdr_Layer()
                        data = []
            data1=[]
            data2=[]
            data3=[]
            data1 = OsmLayers.objects.filter(Layername__icontains=val)
            data2 = Open_Layers.objects.filter(Layer_name__icontains=val)
            data3 = Sdr_Layer.objects.filter(layer_name__icontains=val)
            data.append(data1)
            data.append(data2)
            data.append(data3)  

            return render_to_response('searchresult.html', {'data':data})



        else:
            form = SearchForm()
     else:
        return render_to_response('mapsearch.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Seriously, nothing in the documentation? This is the main thing covered in [part 3 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls).

Comment: i cannot understand how you indented your code. btw, when calling render to response you're still not passing the "num" variable, you need to send {'data':data, 'num': num} to that_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to pass your "num" via the url.

in your urls.py:

```
(r'example_path/(?P<num>\w+)/$', that_view),
```

then inside your view, you can use the num variable as long as you want
check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/ for more info on urls formatting and regular expressions

Comment: I know that I have to pass . What I am not understand is , when a click on a link in a template , how is the num getting passed .

Comment: i guess you're looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/ where basically you use the render_to_response method to pass the page url and some variables (the context) in which you have to put the num

Comment: Still not getting anywhere . I did changes to the urls.py . But not really sure what should I do the views that produces the search

Comment: the view must render an html page with all the variables you need in it. this is accomplished by render_to_response(page,variables), where page is the path to your html template and variabbles is a dictionary with couples <variable> : <value>. The variable you send must have the same name in the urls, obviously. So, as my previous comment said, add 'num': <value> to the variables you pass with render_to_response